# Selecting through Status bar and deleting get merged with next element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor, selection

When trying to delete the selected element through status bar next element is getting merged with deleted element tag.

I have tried this in

1. **CKEDITOR 4.0 and latest version**
2. **Chrome 32.0**

**This problem coming in CKEDITOR demo page itself**

Its happening only in **Chrome Browser**.

See below image, i have selected the `H2` tag.

[image]

And i have deleted that `H2` element, but the next element is now added with in the `H2` tag.

[image]

How can i overcome this problem

Comment: You should submit this bug here. http://dev.ckeditor.com/

Comment: I am new to this. Could you help me

Comment: OK. See this https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11483

Comment: It would be great if you could also test with a later version of CKEditor in case it's already been fixed. Version 4.0 has been out for a while now and there have been multiple fixes done.

Comment: Yes i have tested this with latest version also same problem coming. Its coming in demo page itself

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sfotware bug, not actual programming problem

Comment: have you added an extra <h2> tag by any chance?

Comment: Check the source not the WYSIWYG. There may be some extra h2 tag.

Comment: this should posted in ckeditor bug portal not in stackoverflow as @serges said

Answer (score 1):

I think that you removed the title of H2 but your span is still added to a section H2. You need to remove the H2 section if you want the span to be directly under body.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens sometimes with CKeditor in chrome browser, try deleting browser cache by pressing ctrl+shift+delete in chrome..

Answer (score 1):

There is a opened ticket about this bug in CKEditor. there is also a fix for some cases of this bug (it will fix the problem that describe):

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11861#comment:20